# Is part of Markov chain is a Markov chain?

Tags: markov-chains

I try to solve this question:

> Let X be a Markov chain and let n<sub>r</sub> : r ≥ 0 be an unbounded increasing sequence of positive
>   integers. Show that Y<sub>r</sub> = X<sub>n<sub>r</sub></sub>
>   constitutes a (possibly inhomogeneous) Markov chain. Find the transition
>   matrix of Y when n<sub>r</sub> = 2r and X is a simple random walk.

I tried to develop  this equation in this way:

> P(Y<sub>r+1</sub>=i|Y<sub>1</sub>,..,Y<sub>r</sub>)=
>   P(X<sub>n<sub>r+1</sub></sub>=i|X<sub><sub>n<sub>1</sub></sub></sub>,..,X<sub>n<sub>r</sub></sub>)=???=
>   P(Y<sub>r+1</sub>=i|Y<sub>r</sub>)

Without success and without an idea for the rest of the question. Can someone help, please?

Comment: What is your definition of Markov chain?

Comment: P(Xn+1|X1,...,Xn)=P(Xn+1|Xn)